# IE.ExecWB 17,0 doesn't select all

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

In my VBA script, I have the following two lines which is supposed to select an entire web page and copy its content.

```
IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
```

It works on some web pages but fails on others. It turns out some web pages have one word already highlighted. In this case, "IE.ExecWB 17, 0" doesn't select all. It doesn't do anything and the next line of code copies just that word, not the entire page.

If I intervene and click anywhere on the page to deselect the word, the code then works fine.

Is there anyway to deselect the word programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, looking at the constants for `ExecWB`, in early binding:

```
IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_CLEARSELECTION, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
```

Which translates to `IE.ExecWB 18, 0` in late binding

To solve your secondary issue, you might be able to do something like this:

```
With IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0)
    .Click
    .Focus
    .setActive
end with
```

See if any of the above methods work for you.

Comment: Thanks. The code successfully de-selected the word but the next line of code selected the word again, not the entire web page. I don't know why it behaves differently by code vs. manually. The word was in an input box. Maybe the box was in focus or something. So, when the select command was executed, the word in the input box was selected while manually clicked anywhere on the web page removed the focus from the input box. I don't know. Is there a way to put the web page in focus?

Comment: Thanks but it did not remove the highlighting from the word. In other words, the word was still highlighted after the execution of "IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).Click".

Comment: I try to make a test with the code in this link...https://textuploader.com/dbfrp and this is the output. https://i.postimg.cc/1RCkqFYn/42.gif I find that, even if i select any text on web page then also it is working correctly. You can try to post the URL of web page that can produce the issue. We will try to make a test with it and try to find the solution for it.

Comment: @joehua I added a couple other methods you can try. See if any of those methods within that `With...End With` block help

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks. I thought I had posted the url but I can't find it now. My memory is failing me.

Comment: After some testing,  I found that "IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).Focus" alone is enough to move the focus away from the input box and enable  "IE.ExecWB 17, 0" to select the entire web page. There is no need for "IE.ExecWB 18, 0" or ".Click", or ".setActive". Hope this info will help someone.

Comment: @joehua Glad you got it figured out. I can honestly say I've never had to change focus to the `<Body>` tag, so this was a first for both of us :D